# Where I can find a HTML tag generator?

Tags: video, html

Here's my problem:
I have  video.js, and I alwayes embed the video with a .HTML file and a Iframe.
The strukture is same as always, expect one thing, this thing is, the file name of video.
Would be nice, if I have to be a program, with a one input area, where I can paste the video url, and a button, where I can generate the HTML file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you could create a javascript function with a variable like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var bla= document.getElementById("inputhere").value;

    document.getElementById("area").value = '<iframe width="640" height="390" src="'+bla+'" frameborder="0"></iframe>';

}
</script>

<body>

<p>Enter an URL</p>
    <input id='inputhere'/>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Create html</button><br />
    <textarea id='area' style='width:400px;height:100px;'></textarea>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, but if I typed a javascript in the HTMl file, in this situation paste whole html strukture.
I need a php tag generator or a program for this.
You know, just open it and paste a link and generate, only one need this.

Comment: You can make a single page for this, in which you can enter the url via a textbox as you asked for.

Comment: But, I guess in this case, the URL should be treated as a variable. 
Can you show an example on jsbin?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya235/2/ please note this is pretty ugly

Comment: I realy miss the one thing, the input are, but in start good!

Comment: Here: I was away but here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya235/4/

Comment: Almost, but you can convert it to that when I click the generate button, then save it to a html file?
I promese, this is a last thing, and you get the point :D

Comment: No, you can copy and paste it.

Comment: Okey, thx for your work